# The password of User models is encrypted?

Tags: django, python-3.x, encryption, django-rest-framework

In my model, I extend User model, so the password is from the User model. But when access the objects from `manage.py shell` I can see all passwords from my users.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class User(User, UGCModel):
    pass
```

```
from user.models import User
user = User.objects.all()[0]
print(user.password)
```

Then the print: `12345` that I saved using serializer:

*views.py*

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    lookup_field = 'pk'
    model = User
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserCreateSerializer
```

Is the password encrypted?

Comment: If you can see the passwords, then they are not encrypted. Passwords should **never be stored, plaintext or encrypted**. You store their cryptographic hash, a value that can only be calculated in one direction, from password to hash, never the other way around. I.e. you can verify someone has the right password, not later on look at their password, nor could a hacker that stole your database.

Comment: You should read the docs on extending the `User` model https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: In your case you probably want to be subclassing `AbstractUser` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set password directly. This is explained in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractBaseUser.set_password) and there is an example in the [Django Rest Framework documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)